# Spring Boot Cassandra Reactive WriteTimeOutException problem

Tags: spring-boot, reactive, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to load data in Cassandra of 200000 batch using Spring Reactive Cassandra. Most of the times it runs fine but sometime i am seeing below error resulting in data loss while saving to Cassandra.

```
{"thread":"cluster1-nio-worker-0","level":"ERROR","loggerName":"com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture","message":"RuntimeException while executing runnable org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.DefaultBridgedReactiveSession$$Lambda$1041/1304979740@2b095cbc with executor org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.DefaultBridgedReactiveSession$$Lambda$1042/1415755843@74ca8623","thrown":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraWriteTimeoutException: ReactiveSessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO*******]


Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)","name":"org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraWriteTimeoutException","cause":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)","message":"Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)","name":"com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException","cause":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"Cassandra timeout during SIMPLE write query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
```

Please help me if by any chance i can configure the write timeout in spring boot or some other work around to get rid of this problem(I know batch size is huge and its not idle to use such a big batch but i have constraint to finish this data load in restrictive time line).

Comment: "We have to get things done quickly so the answer is to throw more at the system". Depending on your situation, you could be hurting your performance, not helping it. I don't know your setup, but if you have multiple nodes in your cluster and you're batching into multiple partitions/nodes, you're doing exactly that - hurting your performance, not helping it. If you're inserting into a single partition, then you may be ok. However if you're receiving errors and data loss, again, you're not achieving your goal and may want to back off the size. Have you tried async inserts? Blazing fast.

Comment: Yes i am using async insert

Comment: If you're using batch with async, that's probably not a good idea (never personally done it) - and if you're doing that with multiple partitions, I would think that would be disastrous. I would simply go with they async inserts without batch. Should be able to produce a significant load by itself. If you're still having issues, I'd check on the nodes to ensure you're not overloading them (check for dropped mutations, etc). You may have to back off if it's too much. You may need to add nodes to scale if they're overloaded and you can't reach your SLAs (hopefully good design for scaling).